# Conda: Creating a virtual environment

Tags: python, macos, virtual, environment, conda

I'm trying to create a virtual environment. I've followed steps from both [Conda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#) and [Medium](https://medium.com/@tk2bit/how-to-set-up-and-maintain-conda-virtual-environment-for-your-python-projects-643c8f0c81a1).

Everything works fine until I need to *[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)#Source)* the new environment:

```
conda info -e

# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/fwrenn/anaconda3
test_env                 /Users/fwrenn/anaconda3/envs/test_env

source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate test_env
```

> _CONDA_ROOT=/Users/fwrenn/anaconda3: Command not found.
> Badly placed ()'s.

I can't figure out the problem. Searching on here has solutions that say adding lines to your *bash_profile* file, but I don't work in Bash, only [C shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell) (csh). It *looks* like it's unable to build the directory path in `activate`.

My particulars:

- OS X
- Output of `python --version`:

  ```
  Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
  ```
- Output of `conda --version`:

  ```
  conda 4.4.7
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem. Executing the `source activate test_env` command wasn't picking up my `.bash_profile`, and I normally work in *tcsh*. Simply starting a subprocess in Bash was enough to get `activate` working. I guess I assumed, incorrectly, that the `activate` command would start a child process in Bash and use Bash environment variables.

```
> conda info -e
> # conda environments:
> #
> base                  *  ~/anaconda3
> test_env                 ~/anaconda3/envs/test_env
> bash
~$ source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate test_env
(test_env) ~$
(test_env) ~$ conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
test_env              *  ~/anaconda3/envs/test_env
root                     ~/anaconda3
```

Answer (score 123):

I am not sure what causes the problem in your case, but code below works for me without any issues (OS X, the same version of Conda as yours).

**Creation of the environment**

```
conda create -n test_env python=3.6.3 anaconda
```

Some explanation of [the documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) of `conda create` is not clear:

- `-n test_env` sets name of the environment to *test_env*
- `python=3.6.3 anaconda` says that you want to use *python* in version *3.6.3* in this environment (exactly the one you have, and you can use a different one if you need it) and package *anaconda*. You can put all the things you need there, separated with spaces, e.g., `sqlite matplotlib requests` and specify their versions the same way as for *python*.

**Activation**

```
conda activate test_env
```

**Deactivation**

```
conda deactivate
```

**Getting rid of it**

```
conda remove -n test_env --all
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped, and so did https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: Semantics question: The authour asks about "virtual environment", the answer is regarding an "environment". Is there a difference between the two? I had the impression that a VIRTUAL environment is more light-weight, but maybe I am mistaken

Comment: In general yes, there are differences between virtual and non-virtual environment. In context of this question, no - when you create an environment using `conda create`, it's a virtual one.

Comment: Documentation link was dead.  I found [this](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands)

Answer (score 19):

#### Check if Conda is installed

```
conda -V
```

#### Check if Conda is up to date

```
conda update conda
```

#### Create a virtual environment

```
conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda
```

#### Activate your virtual environment

```
source activate yourenvname
```

#### Install additional Python packages to a virtual environment

```
conda install -n yourenvname [package]
```

#### Deactivate your virtual environment

```
source deactivate
```

#### Delete the virtual environment

```
conda remove -n yourenvname --all
```

Answer (score 0):

Just above the thing @machnic mentioned, a noteworthy thing I need to mention is if the Python version is quite backdated, you may not get it installed.

For instance, I was trying installing 3.6.3 as per @machnic, in this Oct 2023, on my Macbook M1. However, it wasn't installed. After that, when I just shifted it to 3.8, it just got installed.

So, please make sure your Python version is not old. I know it may not be applicable for all cases but this may help.