# Unable to select Virtual Env in VS Code

Tags: python, virtualenv, visual-studio-code

I installed virtual environment for beautifulsoup4 and requests. However, when i am trying to select PYTHON INTERPRETER for the project as my virtual environment it does not show virtual env path rather just the global path.

My Venv path: C:\Users\Farhan Hasant.virtualenvs\HelloWorld--L5nr0Hr

[image]

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106071/how-to-setup-virtual-environment-for-python-in-vs-code/54107016#54107016

Comment: @Sam Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup virtual environment for Python in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106071/how-to-setup-virtual-environment-for-python-in-vs-code)