# Jupyter notebooks in Visual Studio Code does not use the active virtual environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, virtualenv, jupyter

I write Python code in Visual Studio Code and run the program from a terminal in which I have activated a virtual environment, and it works fine.

However, if I create notebook cells using #%% and run those interactively, the virtual environment is not used. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to install ipykernel in the virtual env. pip install ipykernel

Answer (score 109):

It's because there is an extra step needed - you need to explicitly install a Jupyter kernel that points to your new Python virtual environment. You can't simply activate Jupyter-lab or Notebook from the virtual environment. This has tripped me up before, too.

Follow the advice here: *[Using Jupyter notebooks with a virtual environment](https://anbasile.github.io/programming/2017/06/25/jupyter-venv/)*

And, in fact, there can be an issue where your kernel *still* doesn't point to the correct Python binary, in which case you need to change one suggestion in the above advice process:

From: `ipython kernel install --user --name=projectname`

To: `python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=projectname`

where `projectname` is the name of the venv to use as the ipython kernel.

(This correction comes from [a comment to *Jupyter Notebook is loading incorrect Python kernel #2563*](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2563#issuecomment-330472953).)

****and don't forget to restart VSCode***

Comment: Thank you. I set up VS code, updating my WSL from 1 to 2. Hit firewall issues..

Once all resolved - was left with this issue. 

I have never been so happy to find a stack answer before.

Comment: `python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=projectname` command worked for me. thank you so much

Comment: not worked for me!!! inside cell i tried !python --version , still showing other version

Comment: What is a projectname here?

Comment: @OmkarKulkarni it would be the name of your `venv`, which you are defining as your kernel.

Comment: Very well written. I found one thing confusing, so writing it explicitly

`python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=virtual_env_name`

Answer (score 42):

All you need is to edit Vscode settings following these steps:

- Open `Open User settings` using shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Type in search space "env"
- Under Extentions -> Python , you will find **Python: Venv Path**
- Type the absolute path to your enviroment "path/to/myenv/bin" in linux or "path/to/myenv/Script/"
- Restart vsCode
- Select the desired kernel using `Notebook : Select Notebook kernel` using shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

Read more here: https://techinscribed.com/python-virtual-environment-in-vscode/

Answer (score 18):

For VSCode, your Jupyter kernel is not necessarily using the same python interpreter you're using at the command line.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the Command Palette, and select "Notebook: Select Notebook Kernel"

Then choose the interpreter you're using at the terminal

Answer (score 10):

Encounter the same behaviour. Python code works perfectly fine, but Jupyter refuses to pick up the local `.venv`.

- The local venv is in `Python: Select Interpreter` but not in Jupyter's `Select kernel` list.
- The problem is there're too many venv in the system!

If you encounter the same behaviour,

- Press `F1`, then `Jupyter: Filter kernels`, uncheck everything, except the local env.
- Then `F1` -> `Developer: Reload Window`.
  Jupyter will automatically use the default local venv.

Comment: Did the trick for me. Thx!

Answer (score 8):

I find it easy to use `pipenv install ipykernel` to set up the virtual environment with the Jupyter kernel in one go (comment on [rocksteady's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119823/jupyter-notebooks-in-visual-studio-code-does-not-use-the-active-virtual-environm/58134257#58134257)).

Answer (score 6):

for me solved by adding the path of my venv to the settings.json,

now the kernel is detected automatically

"python.pythonPath": "P:\Miniconda3_64bit\venv\Scripts\python.exe",

Comment: the accepted answer didn't work for me, but this solved it.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 5):

On macOS I have .venv/ in the same folder as my .ipynb

```
. .venv/bin/activate
pip install ipykernel
```

Then I restart VSCode in the project folder, open the notebook, and in the `Select Kernel` dropdown I see `.venv/bin/python`

Selecting that, now it works.

EDIT (2 Aug 2023): Now it's no longer necessary to restart VSCode, or to manually `pip install ipykernel`.

Comment: For macOS, I find this the most simple solution. Also, note that 1: you create a virtual environment in `venv` or `.venv` 2: and when you select kernel, you might have multiple suggestions of which `venv/bin/python` is a relative path.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have installed jupyter, notebook, ipykernel libraries in your virtual environment.

Then hit `Ctrl + Shift +P` , press `>Python: Select Interpreter` and choose your path of the venv.

After that, hit `Ctrl + Shift +P` again, run `>Notebook: Select Notebook kernel`.

If you have already opened the jupyter notebook window , reload it again and you can find your path of the venv  in Jupyter's `Select kernel` list.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that worked for me was choosing venv in the upper right corner of VS Code:
[image: Choosing python venv for Jupyter Notebook in VS Code]

Comment: Python: Select Interpreter option was not working, but the option you have shown solved the issue.

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't give me the option of selecting any of my virtual environments. It will let me create a new one ... but then afterwards it isn't selected. And can't be.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do for venv with Jupyter Notebook on VSCode in Windows:

1. Create a venv and get the path to this venv in Windows. As an example, with Anaconda, I get: `C:\Users\rascoussier\Anaconda3\envs\research310`.
2. Now, we need to tell VSCode to use it. In VSCode, go to the Python Extension > Extension Settings. Search for **Python: Venv Path**. Add the path where the venvs are located. Here we added `C:\Users\rascoussier\Anaconda3\envs\research310`.
3. Restart VSCode.
4. Now launch command pallet(`ctrl`+`shift`+`P`) and run `>Notebook: Select Notebook kernel`. Normally the venv python should be available and it should then works.

Answer (score 1):

Using vscode on ubuntu here. For me the solution was to run the command

F1 -> `Notebook: Select Notebook Kernel`

Then Select the venv I had set up. The default was `Xonsh` and was pointing to the system python.

Answer (score 0):

Try a few things:

1. Make sure you can run the code from a Visual Studio Code terminal using the "ipython" prompt with the same Conda environment.
2. If it works then sometimes it is a caching issue, so close your file and open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Now let me show you a scenario. You select the interpreter in Visual Studio Code, and then you write codes below '# %%'. The moment you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you are guessing that the IPython kernel that Visual Studio Code is using is not of the interpreters that you have selected. In this case you could write the following code to conform which interpreter is used for IPython kernel.

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

This shows the executable path that the IPython kernel is using. If you see that it's not taking the correct interpreter then here's something that worked for me.

Just restart your computer. Then reopen Visual Studio Code and reselect the interpreter and again hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now this time Visual Studio Code should take the correct interpreter and its IPython kernel.

[See the final output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdSZZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

If this happens while using **WSL** server, don't forget to install Python in the WSL as well, because it doesn't come automatically from the local installation to the server.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to specify the folders where the environmental variables should be sought for.

Create your virtual environment using conda create --name ENV_NAME e.g conda create --name pwd
Then, conda activate pwd

It Should print out details like this:

[image]

Use that environment location

Edit Vscode settings following these steps:

- Open `Open User settings` using shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Type in search space "env"
- Under Extentions -> Python , you will find **Python: Venv Folders**
  (See the image below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was:

1. Launching Jupyter Notebook locally and copying the localhost URL.
2. In VS Code, `Ctrl + Shift + P` -> `Jupyter: Select Interpeter or Start Jupyter Server`, then pasting the URL.

After these steps, the `venv` interpreter showed up as a `Jupyter Kernel`, allowing to select and run the code.

Interestingly enough, after this step, other python interpreters also appeared.
Check JasonZHM's response [New Virtual environments not listed in Kernels until i reload VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5319#:%7E:text=Same%20issue%20here%20as%20%40guidorice%20and%20%40Mascobot.%20I%27m%20currently%20using%20this%20work%20around%3A:%7E:text=Same%20issue%20here%20as%20%40guidorice%20and%20%40Mascobot.%20I%27m%20currently%20using%20this%20work%20around%3A) for the original solution.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you need to open the entire folder in which your notebook is with VSCode using the "Open with VSCode" option in the folder's option in Windows. If the venv was previously activated (in a terminal for example) then it will be available in the kernel list

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34868900)

Comment: @RamChander: Why don’t you think this provides an answer to the question? I’d prefer more detail, but it’s clearly proposing a course of action.

Comment: @RamChander Sorry, maybe I had to write: "To fix this you need to open the entire folder in which your notebook is with VSCode using the "Open with VSCode" option in the folder's option in Windows. If the venv was previously activated (in a terminal for example) then it will be available in the kernel list"

Answer (score -3):

Try installing the Anaconda Extension pack.

When I code in Visual Studio Code with this extension in the bottom left corner, I can select the virtual environment I want to execute my code in. Hence installing this package should make the trick.

Comment: I think this package has been archived and decommissioned.