# how to select specific kernel for jupyter notebook opened with vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, python-venv

I have created a custom kernel for jupyter notebook using this aproach
[create kernel in venv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58134257/12753324)

The kernel is selectable when opening a notebook

I want to to use this kernel in vs code when working on a `ipynb` file

under `select kernel` I can not find the created kernel
only the default pyton and conda kernels are listed
[image: choose kernel]

how can I add the created kernel to that list/ find the kernel ?

Comment: I have a jupyter.systemd startupscript that loads a pyenv version of python with jupyterlab, and when it starts it give access to any jupyter kernel installed with pyenv and virtualenv having the ipykernel. This can be a standlone server or localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I found a new how to guide [create a kernel in a venv](https://queirozf.com/entries/jupyter-kernels-how-to-add-change-remove)
doing this I can now select the created kernel when activating the venv