# No module named 'sqlalchemy' even though it's installed using venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, sqlalchemy

I installed module, however it still gives me an error. And it's not just sqlalchemy, some other give error as well.

running pip list:

```
(.venv) \\MyProjects\TestProject> pip list
Package           Version
----------------- -------
greenlet          3.0.3  
pip               24.0   
setuptools        65.5.0 
SQLAlchemy        2.0.28 
typing_extensions 4.10.0
```

Interpreter seems to be the one I need, which is my venv.

[image]

so why does it still giving me an error?

[image]

I also specifically pointed python.exe file in vscode settings.

[image]

current interpreter:
[image]

Comment: You're showing us (*in the first image*) a list of recognized environments in your VSCode but not the one selected (*visible in the top-right corner of the window*) for launching the notebook kernel. By the way, you can't do the latter without having `ipykernel` installed. So, based on your `pip list`, you're most likely using the notebook with an environment (*other than* `.venv`) that doesn't have `sqlalchemy`.

Comment: I clicking on the interpreter with the star. Isn't how you select it?

Comment: You seem to have more than one `.venv` (*with the same name*) or maybe you're just selecting the wrong interpreter as I said earlier. Can you show/check the kernel you're selecting for your notebook ? It's in the top-right corner of the window.

Comment: ah! you right. Not the one from venv was selected. Weird.

Comment: Similar answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119823/jupyter-notebooks-in-visual-studio-code-does-not-use-the-active-virtual-environm Adding a downvote to avoid the duplication.