# VS Code: Python Interpreter can't find my venv

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I've been stuck on this for a few days, kindly help me if you can.

I have my venv folder on my root project folder. When I try to set the Python Interpreter, it shows me only the Python installed in my machine and not the one in my root folder.

It was working fine until I formatted my PC and installed windows 10 64 bits. (was running on windows 7 64 bits prior)

Things I have tried:

- Set the path manually via `pythonPath` and/or `venvPath`, in both workspace and user settings:

```
    "python.pythonPath": "F:/Web Dev/Python/Django/project_x_v2/backend/venv/Scripts/python.exe",
    "python.venvPath": "F:/Web Dev/Python/Django/project_x_v2/backend/venv/Scripts/python.exe",
```

[image]

It shows me the correct location in the placeholder but I don't have the option to choose it from the dropdown list:

[image]

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

- In the image it shows "python", but I have corrected it to "python.exe" and it still does not work;
- `~\AppData\...` is located in the disk C:\ while my venv is located in the disk F:. I am not sure whether that is relevant though;
- The venv runs fine in the console.

Comment: The slashes are backwards, in the setup if you look at the offered env path (~\AppData\...) you have backslashes "\" which is normal for windows, but in your configuration you are using drive letters + slash "/", common for unix. I don't have my hands on a windows PC now but ill try to reproduce it later and notify the results.

Comment: I did try it with both types of slashes. No luck. The only way I could make it work was by deleting the venv and re-creating it. (kindly check accepted answer)

Comment: I read the accepted answer it just seems like overkill...

Comment: In this specific case I have found no other solutions, therefore it was not a matter of choice. I beg to differ it is not an overkill though, it doesn't take more than 2 minutes to delete an old venv, install dependencies and re-create it.

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106071/how-can-i-set-up-a-virtual-environment-for-python-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The only solution I found was to delete the `venv` and recreate it. I followed [these steps](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/RebuildingVirtualenvs/) but I'll provide a brief summary for Windows:

1. Activate your virtualenv. Go to the parent folder where your Virtual Environment is located and run `venv\scripts\activate`. Keep in mind that the first name "venv" can vary.
2. Create a requirements.txt file. `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
3. `deactivate` to exit the venv
4. `rm venv` to delete the venv
5. `py -m venv venv` to create a new one
6. `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the requirements.

Comment: Also, for the sake of completeness, the venv should be activated before installing the requirements

Comment: Searched quite a while for this, but only needed to create a `venv`, `activate` it, create the `requirements.txt` file and then execute Python command to get Visual Studio to see `venv` dependencies.  Of course I wanted `django` to see my dependencies, so after `requirements.txt` file creation had to execute the project start command in order to read the dependencies from venv `.txt` file.

Comment: This was the correct solution for me. There was one missing step though, and that was to restart VS Code. Suddenly the venv was activated on restart.

Answer (score 6):

Drop the `"python.venvPath"` setting (it doesn't do what you seem to think it does), don't specify these settings in your user settings, and change your `"python.pythonPath"` to be relative to your project, e.g.:

```
"python.pythonPath": "venv/Scripts/python.exe"
```

Comment: No luck. I removed `venvPath` and added only `pythonPath` to both Workspace and the user settings but still the same. EDIT: Worth noticing I have restarted both VS Code and my computer.

Comment: Any other suggestions are welcome. I can provide any additional information if needed.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it wasn't sufficient to delete and recreate the venv, to select the venv from within VS Code, or to update the pythonPath to point to the venv. VS Code was still unable to find the venv or discover the unit tests. The issue turned out to be that I had reorganized my project folders so my project was no longer in the same location where I originally created its previous virtual environment. The only solution that worked was to delete the venv, move the project back to the same parent folder it was in before, then create a new venv.

Comment: I had the same issue. Any changes in venv folder path will cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for wsl users and maybe it's happening to some of you.

If you did create the virtual enviroment in wsl mode Windows will never find the python file because there is not .exe in Linux systems, so the way to activate is

```
cd [folder where you have your venv]

activate folder -> source venv/bin/activate
```

Once you have your venv activated then open vs code

```
code .
```

And you will have the enviroment activated.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution which worked for me is as follow:

1. Open the VS Code Terminal
2. Navigate (from your project folder) to folder containing the environment and activate as follow:

> ```
> source your_evn/bin/activate
> ```

3.Navigate back to your project folder

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had not yet installed `virtualenv`. You can install it using:

```bash
pip install virtualenv
```