# Visual Studio Code does not detect Virtual Environments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, virtual-environment

Visual Studio Code does not detect virtual environments. I run vscode in the folder where the venv folder is located, when I try to select the kernel in vscode I can see the main environment and one located elsewhere on the disk.
Jupyter running in vscode also doesn't see this environment. I have installed ipykernel in this environment. I tried to reinstall vscode and python extension.

I tried to set the path in settings.json inside .vscode:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": ".\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe"
}
```

Windows 10
Python 3.6.7 (64-bit)
VSCode 1.54.3

Comment: was the virtual environment activated prior to starting code?   I usually have to `venv\Scripts\activate` then `code .`  Then sometime click the bottom left where the interpreter is displayed to explicitly select the correct path.

Comment: As @alper notes below, setting `python.venvPath` to the root of your `pyenv` install or your virtualenv dir solves this pretty neatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found a solution.
Firstly uninstall Visual Studio Code. Go to **C:\Users\Your_profile** and delete the folders related to Visual Studio Code that start with a period. Then turn on showing hidden folders and go to **C:\Users\Your_profile\AppData**. Type vscode in the file finder and remove all folders and files related to Visual Studio Code. Finally, install Visual Studio Code and enjoy the virtual environments. :)

Answer (score 91):

1. In VSCode open your command palette — `Ctrl+Shift+P` by default
2. Look for `Python: Select Interpreter`
3. In `Select Interpreter` choose `Enter interpreter path...` and then `Find...`
4. Navigate to your `venv` folder — eg, `~/pyenvs/myenv/` or `\Users\Foo\Bar\PyEnvs\MyEnv\`
5. In the virtual environment folder choose `<your-venv-name>/bin/python` or `<your-venv-name>/bin/python3`

---

The issue is that VSCode's Python extension by default uses the main `python` or `python3` program while `venv` effectively creates a "new" `python`/`python3` executable (that is kind of the point of `venv`) so the extension does not have access to anything (available modules, namespaces, etc) that you have installed through a `venv` since the `venv` specific installations are not available to the main Python interpreter (again, this is by design—like how applications installed in a VM are not available to the host OS)

Comment: The answer works pretty well. Just rephrasing:  you need to add the python interpreter manually for the first time.

Comment: This did not help with VS Code 17.1.2 on macOS. I had to set the `python.venvPath` variable in VS Code settings for VS Code to recognize my virtual environment.

Comment: Please help this answer up! One of the first, that really helps

Comment: I am experiencing an issue where VS Code doesn't recognize the executables within venv's bin and it says "Please enter a path that exists".

Answer (score 8):

1.In VSCode open your command palette — Ctrl+Shift+P by default

2.Look for Python: Select Interpreter

3.In Select Interpreter choose Enter interpreter path... and then Find...

4.Locate env folder, open Scripts folder , and choose python or python3

> windows - venv

Answer (score 7):

***"python.venvPath"*** is the command to provide the venv path.

In VScode ***settings.json*** add

```
  "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,

  "python.venvPath": "Add_Venv_DirectoryPath_here",
```

Comment: Please add some more context. What exactly does the `activateEnvironment` do? What is the full format of the path?

Comment: this resolved my issue, but I also needed to reboot vs code as a last step. I used ./.venv/bin/python as my directory path.

Answer (score 5):

[VS Code: Python Interpreter can't find my venv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58906183/vs-code-python-interpreter-cant-find-my-venv/58945991#58945991)

> The only solution I found was to delete the `venv` and recreate it. I followed these steps  but I'll provide a brief summary for Windows:
>
> 1. Activate your virtualenv. Go to the parent folder where your Virtual Environment is located and run `venv\scripts\activate`. Keep in mind that the first name "venv" can vary.
> 2. Create a requirements.txt file. `pip freeze requirements.txt`
> 3. `deactivate` to exit the venv
> 4. `rm venv` to delete the venv
> 5. `py -m venv venv` to create a new one
> 6. `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the requirements.

This worked for me, I didn't delete the old, but created a new `python -m venv /path/newVenv` in the ~/Envs folder, `C:\Users\Admin\Envs`. Maybe VS Code is searching in the ~/Envs folder, or it needs to be added to the python.path in the View -> Command Pallete -> >Preferences: Open User Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer. Add this to your user and/or workspace settings.json file:

`"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${env:VIRTUAL_ENV}"`.

Then the first time you launch a workspace from an active virtual environment, vscode will set the interpreter correctly. Thereafter it will use whatever interpreter was set the last time the workspace was closed. As long as you don't manually change it, you're set. For existing workspaces, just manually set the interpreter and vscode will **always** use the interpreter from the **prior session**. It will **never** use anything in settings.json (or .env or .venv) **except the first time** a workspace is launched (and in that case, I think it only uses the settings.json name-value pair shown above).

That will work as-is for virtualenvs managed by `pyenv-virtualenv` (or `virtualenvwrapper`). Should work for regular `virtualenv` too. For `conda`, replace `VIRTUAL_ENV` with whatever it uses, assuming it sets a similar variable. Just activate something and type `env` to see all the environment variables.

This is the solution as long as you create a virtualenv, then launch a workspace for the first time, and the association between the workspace and virtualenv does not change. Unfortunately, it appears you have to set the interpreter manually if the association changes, but you only have to do it once.

The official explanation is [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file), specifically where it says the interpreter is stored **internally** i.e. not in any configuration file exposed to the user:

[image: circled text from vscode documentation showing that they say they store the interpreter from the prior session internally]

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggestions on this thread worked for me. That said, I don't think the issue lies with VS Code, it's venv. I wound up installing PyCharm to fix this. After you’ve downloaded:

PyCharm > Preferences > search “interpreter” > Project:  Python Interpreter > Click ‘+’ > in Virtualenv Environment > New environment (should automatically populate everything for a new env). Select OK, OK, OK.

In the bottom left, you’ll see Git | TODO | Problems | Terminal…etc. Click “Terminal” and you should see your environment already activated. From there, pip3 install your dependencies. Close PyCharm.

Go back to VS Code, open your project, and follow the suggestions above to select the Virtualenv (mine was 'venv': venv) as your interpreter.

Finally resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the confusion here may stem from UI behavior that is at odds with the VScode documentation. The [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment) state:

> When you create a new virtual environment, a prompt will be displayed
> to allow you to select it for the workspace.

That didn't happen in my case (VScode 1.66.2 running on Windows 10 with Remote - WSL plugin version 0.66.2). I followed the steps outlined [here](https://jasonmurray.org/posts/2020/vscodepythonvenv/); I did not see the pop-up described by the VScode docs but clicking on the Python interpreter version in the status bar showed that VScode had automatically selected the interpreter installed in the virtual environment. Furthermore, I did observe that VScode was sourcing `.venv/bin/activate` as described in the post linked above

> Run the code by clicking the play button, note the .venv and source
> “/Users/jemurray/Google
> Drive/scripts/personalPython/helloworld/.venv/bin/activate” in the
> terminal shows the script is activated and running in the virtual
> environment

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error in my scripts with a virtual environment called **"venv"**, so searching the **Visual Studio documentation** I found that the virtual environment starts with a dot **"."** but they never mentioned this, then I created my virtual environment **".venv"** and that fixes the error:

**https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment**

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, I was trying to activate the `venv` in `Windows PowerShell` while the `venv` was created in `wsl`. So, I had to recreate the `venv` with `PowerShell` albeit with different environment name and reinstall the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

After some search I found the next property in the vs-code settings which fix the problem for me: `Python: Env File`, where the default value is `${workspaceFolder}/.env`.
Usually I call my venv folder `.venv` so I fixed the settings to be
`${workspaceFolder}/.venv`.
Now the venv python version appeared in the select interpreter option.

[vs code venv file property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjjdj.png)

Comment: Hey this seems incorrect. I think the Env File is supposed to contain environment variables (see documentation at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file). That's different from virtual environments.

Comment: This exactly what they mentions in the documentation:                                             
  "By default, the Python extension looks for and loads a file named .env in the current workspace folder, then applies those definitions. The file is identified by the default entry "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env" in your user settings (see General Python settings). You can change the python.envFile setting at any time to use a different definitions file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my **Mac**, and found a very easy and simple solution.

I had structured my development folder like this:
`Users/my_user_name/Dev/venv`.

As I had created multiple virtual environments at the same level on the `venv`. The problem is I fill out the `python.venvPath` with `Users/my_user_name/Dev/venv1` (or one of the virtual environment.) This prevents *VS Code* from detecting my other virtual environment. So the fix is very simple. Just change the value of `python.venvPath` from `Users/my_user_name/Dev/venv1` to: `Users/my_user_name/Dev/` and voila, it detects all of my virtual environment.

I hope this answer helps whoever having similar problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please try to use markups in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest vscode version (1.75.1) solved it for me, on fedora I ran

> sudo dnf update code

This triggered re-installation (reload required) and maybe upgrading of the python and jupyter extensions

After the reloads, the python environement in the venv folder was detected again

Answer (score 0):

1. put this in settings.json,

```json
{"python.defaultInterpreterPath":"venv1/Scripts/python.exe",
 "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true}
```

2. Run vscode as admin
3. Run  "set-executionpolicy remotesigned"  in Terminal of vscode
4. Run "venv\Scripts\activate" in Terminal of vscode

Answer (score 0):

Updating VSC Settings -> Workspace -> Extensions -> Python with the python path(/usr/local/bin/python3) solved it for me

Answer (score -1):

If you're a Linux user, and you've used this or similaar to create your virtual environment:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

and you cannot get the debug to work, remove your venv and create it from the VS Code terminal (click Ctrl + back-tick to open).

When you create it from the VS Code terminal, VS Code will ask if you want to use this new environment it amazingly detected for this workspace, say yes.

Answer (score -1):

This issue in VS code was fixed for me my simply using Command Prompt in VS code instead of PowerShell as the Terminal
[image]