# Django virtual environment cannot be recognized by vscode, I tried to select interpreter. And the virtual environment works fine in my local terminal

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, virtual-environment

I'm following the Django tutorial to build my Django project. When I'm running the virtual environment command \Scripts\activate.bat, the terminal information in VScode is cleared but I can't see my virtual environment name at the beginning of my path.

[image]

But if I tried on my Windows terminal, I can see it works.

[image: Can see it in local terminal]

I tried to select interpreter in VS code, but it still doesn't work.
I looked through some threads, but none of them have the same situation with me.

([Visual Studio Code does not detect Virtual Environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66869413/visual-studio-code-does-not-detect-virtual-environments))

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I know.

I need to change the powershell to cmd in VScode.