# Creating new Python function for Azure Functions in VS Code stuck on "Creating virtual environment..."

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am following the instructions from Microsoft on how to create a new Python function for Azure Functions using Virtual Studio Code:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/python/tutorial-vs-code-serverless-python-02

After clicking the option to "Open in current window", VS Code seems stuck on the message:

Creating virtual environment... To skip this step in the future, modify "azureFunctions.createPythonVenv". (1/4) Source: Azure Functions (Extension)

See screenshot below:

[image: VS Code screenshot]

Any insight into what I am doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106071/how-to-setup-virtual-environment-for-python-in-vs-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following two things helped me solve this problem:

1) I selected a new folder and run the following to create a new virtual environment before clicking on creating a new project:

```
python -m venv venv
```

2) I ensured I selected the Python interpreter "Python 3.7.5 64-bit ('venv':venv)" instead of "Python 3.7.5 64-bit". See screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of VS code with two Python interpreters]