# Unable to import 'django.urls'

Tags: python, django

Help please!
am new to django please i have installed django in virtual environment i created on my desktop. but whenever i create a django project and open up the folder in vs code in the url.py file and the wsgi.py files there is a red underline in the import statements. and when i hover over it it says unable to import the package name

this is from the wsgi.py file. it says unable to import django.core.wsgi
i have not written any code so there are no errors yet but vscode shows a red underline on the from import statements

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
```

also in the urls.py file it does the same thing

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
```

i have tried uninstalling and installing django again but it didn't work. it still does the samething

ps. i have not written any code in the django project prior to this but no doubt this will surely give me an error

Comment: Can you show us what exactly is the output? Please do the following in your app please type in `python manage.py shell` then `'from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application` what happens?

Comment: It's likely your VS Code cannot find the virtual environment where you have Django installed. Check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106071/how-to-setup-virtual-environment-for-python-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with your starting project because Django can't import the initial files. You're doing something wrong to install, without a doubt.

Make sure to install Django within the virtual env that you've created and use the Django-admin start project command to install Django

```
virtualenv projectname
```

Activate virtualenv

Next to your folder for virtualenv write in command

```
pip install Django.
```

Note the dot at the end, required to start a project within the folder you're currently in but next to your virtualenv folder

Now it should install Django within env

Next, run

```
python manage.py check
```

If all okay

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Also check your naming of project

Comment: the problem was that i didn't open the file containing the virtual environment and the django project in vscode. i only opened the file that django project file. It worked as soon as i opened the parent file in vs code.(the file that had both the virtual_env file ant the django project file