# Visual Studio not detecting python venv environment

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio

I'm using visual studio for macOS Big Sur. Trying to work with virtual environments for the first time.
So I've created one virtual environment using the following command:

```
python3 -m venv <name>
```

Then I did activate it:

```
source meuvirtual1/bin/activate
```

And I've installed some data science packages through terminal. Everything works fine, however, when I try to use this virtual environment at Visual Studio, it can't detect.

[image: Environments]

Tried to select "enter interpreter path" located the folder, clicked on python3 icon:

[image: selecting path]

But it does nothing. It still can't detect the virtual environment.
The virtual environment is installed at:

```
/Users/rodrigolira/meuvirtual1/bin/python3
```

Can someone please help me?
I've been stuck at this for hours.

Comment: Following link my help to you: [How to setup virtual environment for Python in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106071/how-to-setup-virtual-environment-for-python-in-vs-code)

Comment: wow, it worked! thank you! =)