# Starting fresh without pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I would like to get more experience with the different elements that running and writing python involves. I used Pycharm to start writing code.

Pycharm is great at simplifying the whole process, which includes obscuring even the simplest parts.
I'd like to move my projects to a more hands-on editor.
I really like syntax highlighting and completion so an editor with those attributes is preferred.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Do you have any other requirement regarding new python editor other than it must come *with syntax highlighting and completion*?

Comment: Install vscode install python extension open you code folder in it

Comment: I'm on windows 10 but working towards a move to linux. I'd like more interaction with the terminal

Comment: @Lakpa Thanks :), does vscode make a virtual environment for you?

Comment: Yes you can create it , you can refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106071/how-can-i-set-up-a-virtual-environment-for-python-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use Atom or VSCode. More information about atom can be found here: https://atom.io/
About VSCode try this link:
https://code.visualstudio.com/
When it comes to moving projects to another text editor, PyCharm creates certain files in order to store the scripts, and you can find those files like this:

[as you can see, this is the left side window in pycharm, and next to the title there is a path. That path is where the file is located.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdKGj.png)

You can drag and drop the scripts to the icon of the new text editor in order to open them from there.