# How to add pyodbc to Azure Functions in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions, pyodbc

I would like to use pyodbc, but I seems to not get to Library on Explorer.
I have done "import pyodbc" and "pip install -r requirements.txt"

I see "pyodbc-4.0.32.dist-info" folder in
C:\Users\kenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages

But I don't see in Visual Studio and getting errors from missing pyodbc.

Please instruct me! Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the error might be due to python interpreter selection. On Visual Studio Code you can press `CTRL + SHIFT + P` which will open the command pallet then type in Python: Select Interpreter and select the correct virtual environment. Then try installing the dependencies from requirements.txt.
[image]

If you run into some issues while selecting the venv, you can refer to this thread [How can I set up a virtual environment for Python in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106071/how-can-i-set-up-a-virtual-environment-for-python-in-visual-studio-code)
If it does not help resolving the issue try updating VS Code and/or [Azure Function Extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions).