# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdf2image' error?

Tags: python, pdf, visual-studio-code

I downloaded pdf2image with `pip install pdf2image` on command prompt and keep getting the following error, any clue to what the solution may be ?

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdf2image'`

Comment: you're on windows? Did you create a virtual environment or did you directly install it? If it is windows without virtual env. i highly recommend on creating one first and install yor modules in there. If you created one and it doesn't find the module, did you forget to activate you virtual env?

Comment: You can verify if the installation succeeded by listing all the installed pip modules and seeing if pdf2image is present amongst them.

Comment: Im using VSC, I selected the correct interpreter also. I installed all the pips from the terminal to verify they are downloaded.

Comment: @hyg-cain im on windows, using vsc, installed all modules but its not finding it, how do I activate it ?

Comment: the problem is most likeley that you installed them but since it was directly on windows the PATH variables are not set. Which is a good in most cases. Instead of installing it directly via VSC terminal you should set up a venv. Within that install all modules and then they should also be "available". Take a look at those answers if you want to use VSC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54107016/6074111

Comment: @mislam05 Could you show your launch.json file?

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install pdf2image
```

My **pip** version was **22.0.4.**

This worked for me. What is your pip version?

Comment: Not working even after installing pip version 22.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have installed below packages:

```
conda install -c conda-forge poppler
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
```