# how to activate virtual environment in vs code for django

Tags: unauthorizedaccessexcepti

.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is
disabled on this system. For more information, see
about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- my_env\Scripts\activate
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [],  
    PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Comment: You can check it out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106071/how-can-i-set-up-a-virtual-environment-for-python-in-visual-studio-code