# How to undo the effects of the command `code .` which I executed in my VS Code's terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I executed the command `code .` in my python project's VS Code terminal:

[image: The terminal prompt just before I ran the command.]

I have no idea what this command does. (The reason I executed it was because I was following the instructions in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54107016/1818935).)

Now there's an annoying circle in the terminal's left margin in front of every command line prompt:

[image: A circle in the terminal's left margin.]

What does the command `code .` do? What does the circle in the margin mean? Is there a way to undo the command's effects, including the circles in the margin?

My VS Code version is 1.82.3. My operating system is Windows 10 Pro v. 22H2.