# Cannot install spacy for Python using Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spacy

I'm trying to install spacy for Python using Anaconda and I'm getting an odd error message:

```
python -m venv .env
source .env/bin/activate
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Error Msg:

```
  File "<ipython-input-13-1a465315722a>", line 2
    python -m venv .env
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried several methods and none of them are working.

Any clue how to install this?

Thanks!

Comment: Which operating system and Python version are you using? Please provide more details on the directory structure too.

Comment: I'm on MacOS and using Python 3.7, but I'm using Jupiter on the browser with Anaconda from my machine

Comment: It seems like you're running those commands in the notebook directly as if they were python code, try using the terminal instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running these commands into the terminal instead of the Jupyter Notebook cells directly. If you still want to do it that way, make it right by adding a `!` in the beginning.

```py
!python -m venv .env
!source .env/bin/activate
!conda install -c conda-forge spacy
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating virtual environment like this.
There is an option to [create virtual environments in Anaconda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) with required Python version.

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.8
```

To activate it :

```
source activate myenv   # (in linux, you can use . as a shortcut for "source")
activate myenv          # (in windows - note that you should be in your c:\anaconda2 directory)
```

Comment: For some reason this one's telling me the create command does not exist

Comment: Do you write this directly on the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: @Jason : Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174935/conda-creating-a-virtual-environment