# Trying to import Tensor flow in my jupyter notebook but getting an error

Tags: tensorflow

screenshot of the error I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: Try to update your tensorflow by `! pip3 install -U tensorflow` and then restart your jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [New Virtual Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178776/14290681) in **`Anaconda`** and Try installing the **`Latest Version of Tensorflow`**.

Steps are mentioned below:

```
conda create -n TF_Latest python=3.8 anaconda

conda activate TF_Latest

pip install tensorflow
```

Also, please find [Anaconda Documentation for Installing Tensorflow](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/), for more information.