# Cannot create virtual environment with Mamba/Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, virtual-machine, conda, mamba

I have tried running

```
mamba create -n my_env
```

to which it returns

```
usage: mamba [-h] [--version] [--slow SLOW] [--enable-coverage] [--coverage-file COVERAGE_FILE] [--format FORMAT] [--no-color]
             [--tags TAGS]
             [specs ...]
mamba: error: unrecognized arguments: -n my_env
```

I recently deleted all of my anaconda installations and restarted from a fresh miniconda installation. I'm guessing there may be an error in my .bash_profile, but I am unsure what exactly I am looking for in those files.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59281001/10116997

Comment: Wow, thank you. That fixed it. Don't understand how the way they called the creation of an environment worked and mine didn't, but just glad its fixed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conda: Creating a virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174935/conda-creating-a-virtual-environment)